# PhoneGap/Android multiple Activity created

Tags: android, cordova

Every time I click icon of my PhoneGap app on android's desktop then a new Activity/WebView is created. If I press BACK button then last Activity/WebView is closed and I see previous one.

I do not wish PhoneGap to start multiple Activities/WebViews. I wish my app to have only one Activity/WebView.

PhoneGap version 3.3.0-0.19.3
Nexus 5 KitKat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` attribute to `<activity />` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`